# Filesystemobject permission denied - ways to check / skip?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a tool that copies all files from one folder into 10 seperate folders (all stored on different servers).

Sometimes when running this tool, I will get a permission denied error - which I presume comes down to a user being in one of the files that the program tries to overwrite.

Is there a way to confirm where the error occurs, and on top of that.. is there any way to create a report which shows which files were unsuccessful, but continue running after hitting the error?

Hope this makes sense, it is a generic FSO loop (think it was ron de bruin example)

Can you help? Error handling is definitely not my VBA forte!

I have the variables set before this with the filepaths and a seperate macro for each folder that gets copied - here is the code below

Handling the error is more important for me right now as it would let me pinpoint the issue

```
If Right(FromPath, 1) = "\" Then
        FromPath = Left(FromPath, Len(FromPath) - 1)
    End If

    If Right(ToPath, 1) = "\" Then
        ToPath = Left(ToPath, Len(ToPath) - 1)
    End If

    If Right(ToPath2, 1) = "\" Then
        ToPath = Left(ToPath2, Len(ToPath) - 1)
    End If

        If Right(ToPath3, 1) = "\" Then
        ToPath = Left(ToPath3, Len(ToPath) - 1)
    End If

        If Right(ToPath4, 1) = "\" Then
        ToPath = Left(ToPath4, Len(ToPath) - 1)
    End If

        If Right(ToPath5, 1) = "\" Then
        ToPath = Left(ToPath5, Len(ToPath) - 1)
    End If

        If Right(ToPath6, 1) = "\" Then
        ToPath = Left(ToPath6, Len(ToPath) - 1)
    End If

        If Right(ToPath7, 1) = "\" Then
        ToPath = Left(ToPath7, Len(ToPath) - 1)
    End If

        If Right(ToPath8, 1) = "\" Then
        ToPath = Left(ToPath8, Len(ToPath) - 1)
    End If

        If Right(ToPath9, 1) = "\" Then
        ToPath = Left(ToPath9, Len(ToPath) - 1)
    End If

        If Right(ToPath10, 1) = "\" Then
        ToPath = Left(ToPath10, Len(ToPath) - 1)
    End If




    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath
    FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath2
    FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath3
    FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath4
    FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath5
    FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath6
    FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath7
    FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath8
    FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath9
    FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath10
```

Comment: Yes, please show your code... and also narrow down to specific problem (i.e., handling the error or generating a report -- these should probably be two separate questions...)

Comment: Added the code, and error handling is my priority :)

Comment: Copying entire folders this way would require that you check *EVERY* file in each of the `ToPath#` locations for a lock, if these folders have additional subfolders, then you'd need to recursively check each of these, too.  That could be messy...

Comment: Is there a more succinct way to do this? I am very new, so appreciate there probably is - I couldnt think of a better way of doing it

Comment: Are there any subdirectories in the folder being copied? If not, that makes it a little bit easier...

Comment: Unfortunately there are subdirectories generally, and a decent amount of files too :(

Comment: Are all of the files Excel files? Or do the folders contain all sorts of different files?

Comment: They contain all sorts of files, it is basically an 'information hub' for the place that I work - they have crazy restrictions in place so basically.. it is a 'website' that is stored locally, the sub directories are for each section and their relevant files and it is stored on the different servers just for access reasons.

Basically, it may be that only one of the files in all of the sub directories has been updated so obviously it is crazily intensive for what it could do in theory, but I don't have the skill - prior to me trying this they manually copied everything every day!

Comment: Are the folder structures identical? I mean, when you copy FromPath / ToPath#, does that operation *create* additional subdirectories which did not previously exist? Or are you simply overwriting existing files?  (By now, I hope you can see that the volume of questions I have needed to ask just to get an idea of how complicated the requirements actually are, is that you're in *way* over your head on this and it probably exceeds what anyone is willing to assist you with for free... )

Comment: That is perfectly understandable, I don't suppose I realised the scope of what I was asking and will actually go back to doing some research - don't want to take up any more of your time - at the moment it is overwriting existing files, if I delete the main folder in the other servers and run this macro, it will create a carbon copy of what is in FromPath in each of the ToPath directories. I am happy for you to bow out, you have been helpful in highligting the depth of the waters I'm certainly not swimming in :-)

Comment: Well it would be relatively easy to first attempt to Delete the existing ToPath folders, and see if that operation fails because a file is in use... and not too difficult I think to identify which file(s) are in-use that way.  That might be a more manageable workaround. Thoughts?

Comment: It certainly wouldnt slow the process down as it is overwriting each file anyway, that would definitely make more sense. When I am working on trying to pinpoint the permission errors thus far I am simply commenting out "FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath2" and so on until it gives the error - what you are proposing would be to do that... but recursively? That would certainly work, I'd have thought

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see if this helps out at all. The idea is to use your `FSO` to open the destination folder, and attempt to delete each file & subdirectory in the folder.  This relies on the helper functions `DeleteFile` and `DeleteFolder`.

**Module declarations: Important!**

```
Option Explicit
Dim errors As Collection
Dim file As Object 'Scripting.File
Dim fldr As Object 'Scripting.Folder
```

**This is the main procedure,** note that you MUST declare all of your variables because of the `Option Explicit` at the module level.

```
Sub CopyFolderWithErrorHandling()
Dim FSO As Object 'Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim paths As Variant
Dim path As Variant
Dim FromPath As String
Dim i As Long
Dim ToPath1$, ToPath2$, ToPath3$, ToPath4$, ToPath5$, ToPath6$, ToPath7$, ToPath8$, ToPath9$, ToPath10$

'!!!### IMPORTANT ###!!!
'    Assign all of your "ToPath" variables here:
ToPath1 = "c:\some\path"
'Etc.

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set errors = New Collection

FromPath = "C:\Debug\" '## Modify as needed

If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
    MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
    Exit Sub
End If

'## Create an array of destination paths for concise coding
paths = Array(ToPath1, ToPath2, ToPath3, ToPath4, ToPath5, ToPath6, ToPath7, ToPath8, ToPath9, ToPath10)

'## Ensure each path is well-formed:
For i = 0 To UBound(paths)
    path = paths(i)
    If Right(path, 1) = "\" Then
        path = Left(path, Len(path) - 1)
    End If
    paths(i) = path
Next

'## Attempt to delete the destination paths and identify any file locks
For Each path In paths
    '# This funcitno will attempt to delete each file & subdirectory in the folder path
    Call DeleteFolder(FSO, path)
Next


'## If there are no errors, then do the copy:
If errors.Count = 0 Then
    For Each path In paths
        FSO.CopyFolder FromPath, path
    Next
Else:
    '# inform you of errors, you should modify to print a text file...
    Dim str$

    For Each e In errors
        str = str & e & vbNewLine
    Next

    '## Create an error log on your desktop
    FSO.CreateTextFile(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\errors.txt").Write str

End If

Set errors = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Helper functions:**

The `DeleteFolder` procedure calls on `DeleteFile` for each file at its top level, and then calls itself recursively for each subdirectory in the specified folder path, if any.

The `DeleteFile` procedure logs each error to the `errors` collection, which we then use to write to a text file on your Desktop.

```
Sub DeleteFolder(FSO As Object, path As Variant)

'Check each file in the folder
For Each file In FSO.GetFolder(path).Files
    Call DeleteFile(FSO, file)
Next
'Check each subdirectory
For Each fldr In FSO.GetFolder(path).SubFolders
    Call DeleteFolder(FSO, fldr.path)
Next

End Sub
Sub DeleteFile(FSO As Object, file)
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill file.path
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        errors.Add file.path
    End If
End Sub
```

**Observations**

The error log may contain some duplicates, or near-duplicates, as a lock file may be created, e.g. below. These are usually denoted with a tilde character, but since that is legal in a file name, I do not make any attempt to isolate or ignore "duplicates":

- c:\my files\excel_file1.xlsx
- c:\my files\~excel_file1.xlsx

Certain file types may not raise an error that can be trapped in the above code (.txt for example I think will not error if open in Notepad, etc.). In these cases, the above procedures I think *will* successfully delete the file, but now you have the risk that the user may save the old version over your newly copied version. I don't know how to prevent this from happening; your problem really is an architecture and replication one, and that is not well-suited to be handled by VBA from Excel...

Comment: This was an amazing response, I apologise I didnt answer sooner - didnt have chance to log back in to Stackoverflow - if you're ever in Wales I'll happily buy you a beer (or beverage of choice!)